# Geolocation only shows global map

Tags: iphone, geolocation

I tried to make a goelocation to my iPhone app exactly as shown in this tutorials : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNMNRAbIDoU
my problem is when I build and go i see the map but the geolocation service didn't track my position, so I see just the global map :(
Here is my code I hope you can help me to identifiy the problem :

appdelegate.h

```
    @interface WhereAmIAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    WhereAmIViewController *viewController;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WhereAmIViewController *viewController;
```

appdelegate.m:

```
@implementation WhereAmIAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize locationManager;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.



    self.locationManager=[[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];

    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.locationManager.delegate=self;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter=100;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    }



    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation    {

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.2;


    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.span=span;
    region.center=newLocation.coordinate;
    [viewController.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    viewController.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    viewController.latitude.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    viewController.longitude.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}
@end
```

MyViewController.h

```
@interface WhereAmIViewController : UIViewController {

    MKMapView  *mapView;
    UILabel    *latitude;
    UILabel    *longitude;


}

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *latitude;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *longitude;
```

myViewController.m :

```
@implementation WhereAmIViewController



@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;

- (void)dealloc {


    [mapView release];
    [latitude release];
    [longitude release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: i forget to tell you that i have added the two library Corelocation and MapKit..

Comment: Are you using an actual device or an emulator? AFAIK the emulator does not have GPS but you can probably mock it.

Comment: i use the simulator, but in the tutorial, the author use also the simulator :)

Comment: also, it looks like this video tutorial uses iOS3, not iOS4. Which platform are you targeting?

Comment: if the simulator doesn't have the GPS fonctionality, how does make it work in the tutorial :(

Comment: how can i know if it's iOS3 or iOS4 please, thx ?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:
1) The simulator does not have location, it will always show the lat/long of the Apple headquarters in California
2) It takes a little bit of time for the location to get settled, so if you ask for location right away you won't get one.

Also, you need some more code in your `WhereAmI` view controller. Usually you will see something in the `viewWillAppear`. [Here is a link to a Big Nerd Ranch tutorial](http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=490&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a) on view controllers and map views. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: I have found that while the blue pin is at Apple HQ in the sim, CLLocationManager will find my location regardless when I'm on a Wi-Fi connection, but the pin doesn't move.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here to note:

1) The iPhone emulator does not have GPS capabilities, however it does have a default location of 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA (USA)

2) Your delegate method should be `didUpdateFromLocation`, not `didUpdateToLocation`.

Comment: my problem is that it didn't even track the apple location in cuppertino :(